# Adding Structure Blocks and Content Blocks

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, page-content

How do I create a structure block next to my logo for pictures and a big picture underneath the Navigation menu and a block to display a text "featured products"?  I know how to do it if I made the site from scratch but unfortunately, my client decided he wanted me to use a Magento template and then customize it to the point that it wasn't a magento template anymore.

Picture here:[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't take pressure.. Remember every work has a solution.. For my opinion, just enable the debug tool and start to work on it.. Generally the header portion comes from header.phtml file under page folder of that template.. Even if you not find this part also, I have a cheap solution, what I used when I can't find a file and feel frustrated.. I just start searching using class name.. and most of the cases it helps..

lastly, your client have told you to use a big image above the big discount image.. try it with a static block.. it's faster.. and call this block from that phtml file where this bigger image is coming.. to search the path use the same trick.. search with class name if you won't find it again..

By the way, the home page by default comes from a page- HOME PAGE that is created in admin page of the magento.. you can visit that page to find it.. As it is a custom template, try to visit "local.xml" file under the custom template layout file..